# Пишу ИС по MVP хочу вывести данные на dategrid в виде таблицы как это реализовать?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvp

Я создал сущности и загрузил их на sql server с помощью EntityFramework

```
class context:DbContext
    {
        public context() : base("Connection") { }
        public DbSet<FruitStorage> FuitStorages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sotr> Sotrs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Apple> Apples { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Сell> Сells { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Сhamber> Сhambers { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Пока единственный способ который я увидел это реализовать вывод в Presenter типо:

```
private void Out() 
{ 
context db;//
 var fruit = new Form1<FruitStorage>(db.FuitStorages); fruit.Show(); 
}
```

Это соответствует патерну MVP?

Comment: У вас должны быть три сущности: Model, View, Presenter. Что из представленного вами чем является?

Comment: context является классом Models который работает непосредственно с entityframework.Out это функция которая находиться в Presenter. в View я напишу интерфейсы для ввода данных а для вывода  я не знаю как написать. ведь View интерфейс принимает данные с UI а там дальше presenter работает с ними а при выводе никаких данных не нужно принимать просто сразу нужно вывести бд на datagrid

Comment: Нет, модель в вашем случае - коллекция `FuitStorages`. Кстати, хотя бы исправьте опечатки и не забывайте запятые. / _вывести бд на datagrid_ - нет, невозможно вывести БД. Вы выводите одну таблицу на грид. / У вас жесточайшие провалы в знаниях теории.

Comment: Допустим. Да, я вывожу одну таблицу на грид. Сам способ с помощью которого я вывожу соответствует паттерну MVP?

Comment: Нет, не соответствует. Вы вообще читали определение [Model-View-Presenter](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter)? | Форма - это View (представление), FruitStorages (коллекция данных) - Model. А где презентер?

Comment: Так сама функция вывод out и реализована в presenter

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124656/discussion-between-helloworld-and-alexander-petrov).

Comment: Как можно, глядя со стороны, угадать, где реализована Out? Вы показываете огрызок кода и спрашиваете, на что он похож. Покажите весь код!

Comment: Скинул в чат там описал все что я использую для вывода